# How can I make a rectangular on the moving sprite in Cocos2d android?

Tags: cocos2d-android

```
CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(target.getPosition().x - (target.getContentSize().width),
            target.getPosition().y - (target.getContentSize().height),
            target.getContentSize().width,
            target.getContentSize().height);
```

target is a sprite ... and I make to create a rectangular on the border of the sprite.
I tried to do this work by draw(GL10 gl) but I'm not getting the way to call it .
So, If someone have an idea how to do this . Please help me out of this... thanks in advance

Comment: in cocos2d-iphone there's a macro that enables drawing bounding boxes. Also there's ccDrawLine - rectangle = 4 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void draw(GL10 gl){
        gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glLineWidth(4);
        CCDrawingPrimitives.ccDrawCircle(gl, centerAnchor, 20*scaleX, ccMacros.CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 50, true);

            CCDrawingPrimitives.ccDrawCircle(gl, CGPoint.make((handposition.x-40f)*scaleX,(handposition.y+10f)*scaleY), 45*scaleX, ccMacros.CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 50, true);

            CCDrawingPrimitives.ccDrawPoint(gl, centerAnchor);

        gl.glLineWidth(1);
        gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glPointSize(1);
    }
```

similarly you can draw rectangle by using ccDrawRect() method

Comment: I'll try ang let you know ?